# adding duplicate Analytics cluster to org in Versa Director via API call

Tags: python

Script works, pulling data from a CSV and adding to the Versa director via API.

CSV data:
orgName,parentOrg,globalId,analyticsCluster
child 25,PARENT,2,Cluster-1
child 26,PARENT,3,Cluster-1

i use tkinter to browse for a CSV file, used in SELECT_CSV var.

```
csv_data = pandas.read_csv(SELECT_CSV).fillna('').astype(str)

org_parent_lst = csv_data['parentOrg'].tolist()
org_child_lst = csv_data['orgName'].tolist()
org_globalid_lst = csv_data.index[pandas.to_numeric(csv_data['globalId'], errors='coerce').notna()].tolist()
org_analytics_lst = csv_data['analyticsCluster'].tolist()
```

in the Versa Director admin portal,
workflows -> Organizations -> + -> Analytics Cluster

there is only a single cluster configured.

the amount of times the script adds "Cluster-1" is proportional to the amount of row entries that exist in the CSV.

when navigating to the portal, you can see the same cluster added that many times.

```
post_token_headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {auth_token}"
}

org_child_api = ("https://" + py_dict_load["director_ip"] + ":9182/vnms/sdwan/workflow/orgs/org")

org_data = {
  "versanms.sdwan-org-workflow": {
    "analyticsClusters": org_analytics_lst,
    "globalId": org_globalid_lst,
    "orgName": org_child_lst,
    "parentOrg": org_parent_lst,
  }
}

for _, row in csv_data.iterrows():
    org_data["versanms.sdwan-org-workflow"]["globalId"] = int(row['globalId'])
    org_data["versanms.sdwan-org-workflow"]["orgName"] = row['orgName']
    org_data["versanms.sdwan-org-workflow"]["parentOrg"] = row['parentOrg']
    org_data["versanms.sdwan-org-workflow"]["analyticsCluster"] = row['analyticsCluster']

    response = requests.post(org_child_api, 
                             json=org_data, 
                             verify=False, 
                             headers=post_token_headers)
```

adding the string "Cluster-1" to org_data works as expected. only a single entry for each

```
org_data = {
  "versanms.sdwan-org-workflow": {
    "analyticsClusters": "Cluster-1",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i just figured it out.
reading the API documentation (and finally understanding) and seeing the typo in my code.
per API doc:

```
  "versanms.sdwan-org-workflow": {
"analyticsCluster": "string",
"analyticsClusters": [
  "string"
],
```

analyticscluster expects a single string
while analyticsClusters expects an array.

in my code above i was referencing BOTH.

my org_data referenced analyticsClusters while my loop referenced analyticsCluster
i updated all parts for analyticsClusters and updated by loop:

```
org_data["versanms.sdwan-org-workflow"]["analyticsClusters"] = [row['analyticsClusters']]
```

everything works as expected